# How to print one text line including spaces using fprintf

Tags: c, printf

My question is how do I create a format string that will include an entire line of text including embedded spaces?

I have a buffer defined

`char buf[380];`

When I read in a line of text, I make sure that `buf[378] = '\n';` and `buf[379] = '\0';'

I am editing that buffer and then writing it to an already-opened file using `fprintf`:

`fprintf(outfile, buf);`

I am getting this warning when compiling:

```
ex_split.c: In function ‘main’:
ex_split.c:65:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
```

and am not quite sure how to write the format string so all of buf can be written, because, as I remember it %s will stop at the first space, and this data has lots of spaces in it, which I need. It is positionally formatted data.

***Addendum***

Let me restate the problem. I believe %s will cause fprintf to stop scanning at the first 0x20 character in each line of data, in which there are one or more and usually many space and non-space, readable ASCII data. Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` stops at a space when scanning as part of a `scanf` format, not when printing as part of a `printf` format. `fprintf(outfile, "%s", buf);` will work just fine for you.

If you're sure that your `buf` string is safe - that is, it doesn't contain any `%` escapes that might cause undefined behaviour in `printf`, you could also just ignore/disable the warning in this case.

Comment: If you "know" that the string is safe, there's always a chance that you're wrong. Using `"%s"` gives you one less possible error to worry about. Or, since the OP doesn't actually need to format anything, `fputs(s, outfile);` is probably a better solution.

Comment: I'd like the warning to clear, which is why I asked the question. And what's weird, is on CentOS 5, I don't get the warning with obviously a different version of gcc than Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
fprintf(outfile, buf);
```

to

```
fprintf(outfile, "%s", buf);
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: @CarlNorum So, the OP knows that "it will work as expected", but also "doesn't think it will work"? ;-)